# How can I make long section titles wrap all the way to the margin?

Tags: sectioning, section-titles

LaTeX by default indents section titles so that the left edge of the text is in alignment, as follows:[image: Text is indented and aligned on left-hand side]

I would like to make it wrap all the way to the left margin, as shown:

[image: Text is wrapped to margin]

How could I do that? I thought of the `titlesec` package, but it does not seem to provide a way to do it. (Yes, I know this formatting is ugly, but I would like to know how to do it.)

Minimum working example that I have so far:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`titleformat` from `titlesec` is usually the way to format sections (link to [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)). In your case, change the default *shape* from `[hang]` to `[block]`. Extra spacing can be adjusted by `\titlespacing*` define in the same document. There are also some example definitions of the default and more fancy formats, so you may want to have a look at those, as well.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}


\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The KOMA-Script classes provide their own interface to configure headings. To not use hanging headings, just remove the `\@hangfrom` from the default definition of `\sectionlinesformat` (shown in the user manual):

```
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses]{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{\hskip#2#3#4}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the example I've also used option `emulatestandardclasses` to make the KOMA-Script classes more lookalike to the standard classes.

If you want to distinguish the different levels, you can use the first argument: If you also want justifying (and hyphenation) of the headings, you can redefine `\raggedsection`:

```
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses]{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}{\hskip#2#3#4}{\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\raggedsection{\noindent}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit esse est.}

\subsection{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the levels `\part` and `\chapter` there are different commands `\partlineswithprefixformat`, `\chapterlinesformat`, and `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`. See the user manual for more information.

Answer (score 2):

To do the same thing in the `memoir` class, use the `\sethangfrom{}` command, as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\sethangfrom{\noindent #1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\subsection{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Note that this macro will affect *all* the lower-level sectioning commands at once.

Output:
[image: All sectioning headings are block text.]

If you want to change just one section level (say, subsections but not sections), use the `\setNhook{}` macro, where `N` refers to the short name of the sectioning command. Here is a list of commands to use:

| Section type | Short name | Command |
| --- | --- | --- |
| section | sec | `\setsechook{\sethangfrom{\noindent ##1}}` |
| subsection | subsec | `\setsubsechook{\sethangfrom{\noindent ##1}`} |
| subsubsection | subsubsec | `\setsubsubsechook{\sethangfrom{\noindent ##1}}` |
| para | paragraph | `\setparahook{\sethangfrom{\noindent ##1}}` |
| subpara | subparagraph | `\setsubparahook{\sethangfrom{\noindent ##1}}` |

Note that the argument must be preceded with two pound signs (##) instead of one.

The following code formats subsections as block text, but creates the default hanging indent for sections:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\setsubsechook{\sethangfrom{\noindent ##1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\subsection{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Only subsections are block text.]